# How to get sk_buff_head in kernel driver?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver

I currently write a network driver, and in the transmit function I want to modify the socket buffer queue. Therefore I need to get the lock of `sk_buff_head`, but the link to the head from a socket buffer was removed years ago.

How can I access `sk_buff_head` from `ndo_start_xmit(struct sk_buff *skb, net_device *dev)`?

I am using current linux kernel 4.15.3.

### Background

I modify an existing driver for a virtual network device to implement fragmentation which relies on the order of frames, so the second fragment must be sent directly after the first fragment. It works on layer 2 frames.

Therefore I hook up in the `start_xmit`function, simplified it looks like this:

```
static spinlock_t xmit_lock;
start_xmit(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev)
{

    [...]

    if(skb->len > TRESHHOLD) {
        second_skb = do_fragmentation(skb);
    }

    [...]

    spin_lock_bh(&xmit_lock);

    if(second_skb) {
         second_skb->next = skb->next;
         second_skb->prev = skb;
         skb->next = second_skb;
    }

    ret = dev_queue_xmit(skb);

    spin_lock_bh(&xmit_lock);
}
```

So I want to reach that both skbs are sent in exactly this order, there should not be a frame sent in between which passes this driver. This works, when using ping flood mode oder iperf with UDP but sometimes it messes up with iperf using a TCP connection. Then, there are some cases where the order is messed up.

To solve this, I thought I need the "real" queue lock for the skb and so I need `sk_buff_head` for this.

Comment: are you using v4 kernel?

Comment: Yes, sorry, added this information

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what it is you're implementing, preferably with some code? e.g. are you trying to re-implement sth to the effect of `__dev_queue_xmit` or `netpoll_send_skb_on_dev`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I think now it is much more understandable what I want to reach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this correctly you need to set up a local lock in a private data structure:

e.g.

```
struct my_protocol {
    spinlock_t lock;
}
```

set it up during the dev->`open` (usually done in an allocation routine) using `alloc_netdev()` and then you can access the structure using `netdev_priv` and hold your lock.

Comment: But then I just have some lock in my driver, but I want to get the lock for the skb queue so that nothing else can modify the queue. Furthermore I then can use the skb functions to modify the queue.

Comment: aaaah you want to get the skb_buff_head for a given queue, well you can use `container_of` for that. Let me see if I can modify my answer

Comment: Yes, I want access to the queue the current skb is in

Comment: but how do you know that the skb is not dequeued already by net core?

Comment: Hm, I do not know. But is there no transmission queue? I am writing a virtual network device driver and transmit one using a physical or underlying device. I want to get the queue to make sure I do transmit another new skb directly after it.